# Faster way to read from Socket with ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, tcp, bytebuffer

I have connected by TCP to a socket which is constantly sending a large amount of data, which I need to read in. What I have so far is a byte buffer that is reading byte by byte in a while loop. But the test case I am using right now is about 3 MB, which takes a while to read when reading in byte by byte.

Here is my code for this explanation:

```
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(3200000);
while(true)
{
     int b = in.read();
     if(b == -1 || buff.remaining() == 0)
     {
           break;
     }
     buff.put((byte)b);
}
```

I know that byte buffers are not thread safe and I'm not sure if this could be made faster by possibly reading in multiple bytes at a time and then storing it in the buffer? What would be a way for me to speed this process up?

Comment: Are you reading the same socket from multiple threads? Are you passing the filled buffer to another thread? Why do you mention thread safety at all?

Comment: In any language (I know very little Java), if you only process read data 1 byte at a time, you're doing it wrong. Read in blocks, process the blocks 1 byte at a time.

Comment: @erickson I'm not using threads. I stated that because I have read elsewhere that ByteBuffers are not thread safe. But yes I am reading from a single socket.

Comment: @SanJacinto That is what I was assuming as well haha. Do you know of some sort of standard of which to read in bytes. (By this I mean how many bytes should I read into one block at a time? Is there a standard amount?)

Comment: It will largely depend on your application. In general, you read as much as your scenario will permit, and this differs from one scenario to another.

Comment: Why? Why can't you use either a SocketChannel or a byte[] array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bulk read instead of a single byte read.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[3200000];
int pos = 0;
while (pos < buf.length) {
  int n = in.read(buf, pos, buf.length - pos);
  if (n < 0)
    break;
  pos += n;
}
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf, 0, pos);
```

Instead of getting an `InputStream` from the socket, and filling a byte array to be wrapped, you can [get the `SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getChannel%28%29) and [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) directly to the `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: I believe this works, I'm running it now, but I'm not entirely sure how much faster it will be. But I have another question, is there a way to read from the socket without know the amount that will be sent? (In other words, an unknown buffer size)

Comment: @GBoggs Do you mean that you want to avoid having a hard-coded maximum, like 3200000 in this example? Instead, have memory allocated dynamically as needed to fit the data read from the socket?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

1. Use `Channels.newChannel()` to get a channel from the input stream and use `ReadableByteChannel.read(buffer).`
2. Get the `byte[]` array from the buffer with `buffer.array()` and read directly into that with `in.read(array).` Make sure the BB really does have an array of course. If it's a direct byte buffer it won't, but in that case you shouldn't be doing all this at all, you should be using a SocketChannel, otherwise there is zero benefit.
3. Read into your own largeish byte array and then use a bulk put into the `ByteBuffer`, taking care to use the length returned by the `read()` method.
4. Don't do it. Make up your mind as to whether you want `InputStreams` or `ByteBuffers` and don't mix your programming metaphors.